# Painting garage in two parts with the exact same paint, but the second part came out grayer and not glossy at all

Tags: paint

I really don't know what happened or what messed up. This is the sequence of events:

- Due to time constraints and bad weather we had to paint in two different days for a garage wall & ceiling paint.   We aimed for temperatures around ~65 degrees F as that was the best our city was getting in the next few weeks.
- We divided the garage in half and painted one half of it the first day and the other half the second day.
- On the first day (to paint the first half of the garage) we waited for the weather outside to be around ~65 F before starting the job. We applied primer as usual, waited for it to dry for 4 hours, then applied a 1st coat of paint. After this coat of paint dried the color came out just as we had purchased the color -- Glossy, and White.
- On the second day (to paint the other half of the garage), the temperature outside differed from the predicted forecast, so we had to paint at around ~60 F.   We applied primer as usual, waited for it to dry for 4 hours, then applied a 1st coat of paint. This paint came out much more grayer, and the finish wasn't glossy but rough, like the texture of drywall.

In both jobs we used the same exact primer and the same 1st coat of paint, yet the colors and textures came out wildly uneven between each half of the garage.   We made sure to use new rollers in-between days, and tried to keep the temperature while painting consistent for consistent coverage.

Trying to figure out what went wrong...

EDIT:  I am a S-class graded idiot.  I mistakenly swapped the use of the primer and 1st coat and didn't even check the label when both buckets of paint were similar colors.  Dummy mistake

Comment: Did you check the humidity?

Comment: @SolarMike Y'know, I did not. Lemme check what the weather report said.

Comment: @SolarMike It was 47% humidity the day we painted the first half, and 44% the second half.  We tried painting a small spot in the garage today (at 60% humidity) and the color came out akin to the results at 44% humidity -- gray, and non-glossy

Comment: Were the cans expose to cool/cold night temperatures or were they inside a heated building?

Comment: @crip659 They were stored in our garage overnight, temperatures here are around 30 degrees F overnight. We did make sure to have the paint properly mixed before applying the paint each time though!

Comment: Think paint likes to be stored above 50, if it got cold, it could be the reason or the paint it self was cold when painting the second time.  Air temperature is one thing, surface and paint temperature can be another different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the comments are spot on but without knowing exactly what kind of coating,i.e. the primer and finish, it's hard to say for sure.

Was it an acrylic, water-based floor coating? Was it a solvent-based coating?

Was it epoxy and if so, waterborne, polyamide, polyamine, aliphatic urethane?

Polyamines are very sensitive to moisture.

Moisture and temperature variances are usually the cause of what you described.

I am a General Manager at a local retail paint store for 21 years and these are the questions I would ask my customer.

Edit: To answer your question below: Yes, adding a final coat of the correct finish will help. In some cases the floor where the mistake needs to be stripped to the concrete. Hopefully, a final coat will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for responding!   It was a latex-based paint, but after checking the label like you advised we found out exactly what our problem was.   I totally flubbed up, put the 1st coat on first, then the primer second by not carefully reading the paint bucket I was using, which explains why the second coat came out so much more rougher.  Ouch.   I guess we can just paint over the 2 layers of paint with the real paint now?